# file_get_contents work with direct typed url and not with automatically obtained url

Tags: url, static, file-get-contents

I have a strange situation with **file_get_contents**.
A webservice returns me an **url**, so with that **url** I use **file_get_contents**() to get the content of the file from that url.

something like:

```
$url = $result_from_webservice->url;

if( file_get_contents( $url ) ){
    echo 'ok';
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

the result of that pice of code whas "**error**".

so I have tried to set **$url** var directly. I have display the url result

```
echo $result_from_webservice->url;
```

from witch I have obtained the url like:
    https://site.com/page.php?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2

and then I used the direct result like:

```
$url = 'https://site.com/page.php?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2';
```

and surprise.. that worked (result = "ok").

then I tried to apply urldecode, thinking that my smart browser has tried to smooth the page content.

```
$url = $result_from_webservice->url;
    $url = urldecode( $url );
```

but no success.

I have allowed php to print all errors and no errors, no warnings, no notice.

Do someone has an idea about what happens here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast the URL to a string before using it:

```
$url = (string)$result_from_webservice->url;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I have tried your solution and still doesn't work

Comment: @stef, what does it display if you do `var_dump($result_from_webservice->url)`?

Comment: So.. **var_dump( $result_from_webservice->url )** result, is string(126), while the length of the displayed url is 122. 
In that url is an **&** printed just like that, but even if the real form is **&amp;** (which is not), that problem shouldn't be solved by **urldecode()**?

Comment: @stef, yes that's the problem. You need to decode it not with urldecode() but with `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: @stef, by the way, when you do a `var_dump` you should view the source to view the data exactly as it is.